# CoSign API: Signing a PDF stream using SAPI?

Tags: digital-signature, cosign-api

In my project I'll work with stream from PDF. Can I add customized signature on the fly to stream?
I have downloaded example Buffer Sign. It signs document, but without place signature.
In my project I need to add customized signature in the proper place as in PDF example:

```
string FileName, string FieldName, string User, string Password,
  string SignPassword, int page, int x, int y, int height, int width,
bool Invisible, string Reason, int AppearanceMask, string NewFieldName,
  string GraphImgName
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use SAPI CreateFileHandleByMem function to create a file handle.
2. Use SignatureFieldCreateSignEx2 function to create and sign a signature field.
3. Use GetFileMemData function to retrieve the signed byte array.

You can find all the documentation in the [SAPI Manual](http://www.arx.com/files/DOCUMENTS/SAPI-Signature-API-v6.2-Programmer-Guide.pdf).