# CoSign API: Signing a BYTE stream using SAPI?

Tags: digital-signature, cosign-api

I would like to extend the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813952/cosign-api-signing-a-pdf-stream-using-sapi) for other types of byte streams. I would like know how can I map byte streams extension to SAPI_ENUM_FILE_TYPE? I know that pdf files should be mapped to SAPI_ENUM_FILE_TYPE.SAPI_ENUM_FILE_ADOBE however I am not quite sure how to perform it for other type of files (e.g. Office documents)

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the online [documentation](http://docs.arx.com/sapi/Default.htm#doc/SAPI_ENUM_FILE_TYPE.htm#SAPI_ENUM_FILE_TYPE):

> SAPI_ENUM_FILE_NONE - Not in use.
>
> SAPI_ENUM_FILE_WORD - Word file (.doc file).
>
> SAPI_ENUM_FILE_ADOBE - PDF file (Adobe).
>
> SAPI_ENUM_FILE_TIFF - TIFF file.
>
> SAPI_ENUM_FILE_DETACHED - Not supported in the current version.
>
> SAPI_ENUM_FILE_P7M - Not supported in the current version.
>
> SAPI_ENUM_FILE_XML - XML File. Supported from version 5.
>
> SAPI_ENUM_FILE_OFFICE_XML_PACKAGE - Office 2007 file type (.docx file or .xlsx file).
>
> SAPI_ENUM_FILE_INFOPATH_XML_FORM - InfoPath 2007/2010/2013 form (.xml file).

Comment: Hello Almog, Thank you for your answer. I can determine the type of the byte stream usign magic numbers and zip part analysis(docx/xslsx). Then I would create a handle by memory but  createhandlefrommemory method can only be used with pdf and xml files. I need to sign doc/docx/xslsx/xsl files on the fly as well not only pdfs. Is there a way to do it? (without creating a temp file) When I sign a buffer it returns only signature, not signed buffer. There must be a way to do it.

Comment: @conapart: Signing documents from streams by using SAPI Memory File Handles is supported only for PDF and XML formats. For signing other document formats you will need to store the document as a temp file.
Note that in order to sign an Office document you will have to create the signature field in advance within the document. This is not required for PDF and XML. 
Note also that signing a data buffer with SAPI will always create a detached PKCS#7 signature. SAPI does not embed a signature on a buffer within the buffer itself since the buffer format and structure is not known nor required.